# Could not access the developer workspace

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm connecting as system administrator on Dynamic AX 2012, when starting developer workspace I have an error message which is: "insufficient right to access to developer workspace"

What is the problem?

Image showing error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start the AX 2012 application, maybe you are not an AX admin?

Comment: no I'm admin (system administrator = sysadmin) but i have an expired license (( I'm finding for an other license now ))